# Bar button item image (UIImage) color changes with tint color?

Tags: ios, swift, xamarin.ios, uibarbuttonitem, rightbarbuttonitem

I am trying to set an image for bar button item based on a condition. I need to show 2 different images. The tint color property is affecting the color of my image itself. How to change this? When i give “clear color” as tint color the image is not getting displayed at all.

Comment: share the code you are using..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this

**Swift 2.x**

```
var image = UIImage(named:"myImage").imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysOriginal)
```

**Swift 3.x or 4**

```
var image = UIImage(named:"myImage")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
```

And set it to your UIBarButtonItem

Comment: @subin272 Accept the answer for others?

Comment: Didn't get you ?